# Double click needed in firefox (JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was advised to used this because i was having a problem, a link worked in FireFox ONLY when clicked the second time. This is to display an external html in a div called leftColumn.

```
$(function(){
  $('#ulWithAllTheLinks').delegate('li a', 'click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault;
     $('#leftColumn').load(this.href);
  });
});
```

My question is, that this displays the html with the content in a NEW page, I know that it has something to do with this:

```
<ul id="one">
  <li><a href="content.html">First Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

yet i don't know how to link this to the function

Comment: What exactly is your question? There seems to be a few issues going on...

Comment: you say "My question is," then you make a statement. What is your question here?

Comment: Simply asking how he can stop the hyperlink from behaving in the default manner, i.e. how can you stop the browser following a link that is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is a function, so you need parenthesis on the end, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#ulWithAllTheLinks').delegate('li a', 'click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#leftColumn').load(this.href);
  });
});
```

Without the [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) (or `return false;`) working correctly, the *default* behavior will occur...going to that page.

Comment: I've always preferred `return false;` - but is the former a more efficient approach?

Comment: @jakeisonline - It depends what you're after, for example if there was another handler above this, like a `$("a").live(...)` then `return false` would stop the event dead in its tracks, preventing the bubble as well, whereas `e.preventDefault()` wouldn't.  As a general rule, I use the "lightest" method to do what's needed...it avoids having to track down where the event's stopping...I only stop it if I have good reason to do so.  That being said, it's mostly preference, the actual performance difference for an event is infinitesimal.

Comment: ah, that makes a lot of sense. I guess I've always just needed to stop the event dead in its tracks.

Comment: @ber - Welcome :) Be sure to accept answers on this and future questions via the checkmark beside the answer that helped resolve it :)